# Font protrusion --- who really uses it?

Tags: typography, protrusion

Apart from the paradigmatic appeal to some of Gutenberg's Bibles, I have not seen further actual examples of texts typeset using font protrusion and hanging punctuation. Indeed, as a scholar and a typesetter, I haven't bumped yet into any real examples of people actually using these typographic features. I wonder, accordingly, whether the fuzz about XeLaTeX supporting (or not) them is worth the while.

So apart from all their typographic merits, do people actually use these features? (Or are they rare as, say, historical ligatures?)

Comment: Maybe you're not looking close enough? In my experience, ever since the hz-program has been introduced in InDesign, protrusion has been used a lot for magazines, books and printed matter of all kinds. Of course, I cannot provide any statistics, but I stumble upon it frequently.

Comment: Perhaps, that's what I'm trying to determine.

Comment: How about the reverse?  Once I became aware of the possibility, now all I notice is when it is *not* being used.  I suppose if the punctuation hangs too much, it can look ridiculous, but a modest value makes the right-hand side of the page look nicer / more even (to me).

Comment: Might also be a cultural thing: I did notice that it's much more often used in books published by German houses than by British/American ones. By just skimming through a couple of books here, I already found samples by Rowohlt, Suhrkamp, and Hanser (three major German publishers).

Comment: Yes, I haven't noticed it in Anglo-American books, at least not in those coming from university presses.

Comment: This looks very borderline for on-topic to me: it may be interesting, but it's not TeX-dependent (InDesign has already been mentioned, quite reasonably).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typography and as is, it belongs to [GD.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11):

The point of hanging punctuation is not that you notice it, but rather that you don't notice it (as with most aspects of typography), i.e., the idea is to get the margin more uniform not to have letters stick out into the margin.

As an example of use inthe TeX world: The LaTeX Companion makes use of it and you can examine a sample chapter at http://latex-project.org/guides/books.html  (chapter 3 is provided as a pdf)

I used fairly small protrusion values (depending on shape of the characters) but on a good number of letters, whether I succeeded or not in providing better quality is of course open to debate.